# Why does MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection() error "Adb rejected adb port forwarding command: cannot bind socket"

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

When I try to get a device with MonkeyRunner I get this message:

> > > newdevice = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
> > >       110804 17:35:28.561:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] Adb rejected adb port forwarding command: cannot bind socket
> > >       110804 17:35:28.561:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice]com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: cannot bind socket

I'm running monkeyrunner.bat from the commandline in windows Xp with JDK 1.6.0_26, Python 2.7.2, and Android SDK 11.  adb devices shows my USB device.

Comment: try running the "adb kill-server" command and if that does not work then try restarting your computer

Comment: Use **sudo monkeyrunner** instead of **monkeyrunner**. It works for me on Mac OS X Lion.

Comment: Thank you, restarting ADB (`adb kill-server`, then `adb start-server`) worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I also had come across this problem but killing and restarting the adb server din't solve the issue.
I have solved it with below procedure

1. open command prompt and run below command
   netstat -ano
   This lists all PID and port numbers.
   Make a note of PID listening on port 12345
2. Go to task manager->Processes tab
   and from View->Select Coloumns Tick the PID field.
   Now kill the process with PID noted in previous step.

Now the MonkeyRunner proceeds further.

**Note:**

12345 port is identified from AdbChimpDevice.java in chimpchat.jar 
located in

..\android-sdk-windows\tools\lib\chimpchat.jar